# InstantiateIn and user controls

Tags: asp.net

I want to add my user control in InstantiateIn like this:

```
public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        PIMVisualizer pimVisualizer = new PIMVisualizer();
        container.Controls.Add(pimVisualizer);
        container.Controls.Add(new Button() {Text="asdf"});
    }
```

but the control doeas not appear on the page (the button does). The control is trivial, I am just testing the approach:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PIMVisualizer.ascx.cs" Inherits="PIMVisualizer" %><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="UC"></asp:Label>
```

but still, why does not the text "UC" appear onthe page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) UserControls, do not create them via constructor.